# window location replace only works when page is refreshed

Tags: jquery, hash

I'm looking for any creative (and simple) solution to the following issue -

This thing only works onload, but not onclick:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]> 
   <script type="text/javascript">
   if (window.location.hash == '#aciw') {
       window.location.replace("#checkout-counter-aciw");
   }
   </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Thus, if the user goes to www.site.com, and clicks on a link that inserts #aciw into the browser, nothing happens. On the other hand, if he hits refresh with www.site.com/#aciw in the browser, the hash changes to www.site.com/#checkout-counter-aciw and all is well.

Of course, I don't want this to only work onload, I want it to especially work onclick, as I have a couple of links that need to send IE8 to a completely different location.

I've been playing around with adding this:

```
window.location.hash = "#" + checkout-counter-aciw;
```

and this:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

But so far it only momentarily takes them to #checkout-counter-aciw and then it snaps back up to the top of the site.

Answer (score 1):

Listen to the `hashchange` event. It'll tell you when it changes.

```
$(window).on("hashchange", function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure how to implement this.

Comment: This example is based on jQuery library, include it before script and all should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this, and it works:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]> 
<script type="text/javascript">

if (window.location.hash == '#aciw') {
    window.location.replace("http://www.site.com/#checkout-counter-aciw");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
        $('a.aciw').click(function(){  
           window.location.replace("http://www.site.com/#checkout-counter-aciw");
        });
});

</script>
<![endif]-->
```

For my own personal notes:
So the first part ("if") works if the initial requested page already includes the #aciw hash,
and the second part (click function) works if they first arrived at www.site.com (with no #aciw hash) then click on the .aciw link.